# How can I pass a parameter of Smarty to a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, smarty

I am trying to pass a parameter from `Smarty` to a `Javascript` function but I cannot achieve that.

This is where I use my Smarty:

```
{foreach $galery->getObjects() as $object}
    <div class = "divObject"><img onclick = "showObject({$object->getName()})" src = "{$galery->getPath()}"></div>
{/foreach}
```

and this is my function in `Javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function showObject(object)
     {
        alert(object);
     }
</script>
```

where object it is an `String` (the name of the `Object`) but it does not work (the alert it is not being shown on the page).

Is there a way to do that? What I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean `"it doesn't work"`? What does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @Shomz When I `onclick` on the image the alert it is not being shown.

Comment: Your javascript argument is not passed as a string. You need to quote {$object->getName()}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `{$object->getName()}` outputs a string, you still need to quote it in Javascript, like this:

```
onclick="showObject('{$object->getName()}')"
```